# Is it possible to set gitlab-ci expire in value for artifacts depending on job success?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want artifacts for successful jobs to expire in 1 hour, but for failed jobs to expire in 1 day. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple artifacts aren't possible yet. You can find the [current proposal here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/18744)

You can define multiple paths for the artifact:

```yaml
job:
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - failure_file
      - success_file
```

Without any error, it will ignore the file if it doesn't exist.